# How to use plotly buttons and plotly.express (px), with the color option?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

When using `px.scatter(color='key')` with the color option, using plotly buttons behaves erractic. The data is after clicking on either of the buttons is jumbled up and not what one expect, certainly does not go back to the original plot when clicking on Plength (the button for showing petal_length on the y-axis), which is what we started with. What is going on?

Works fine:

```py
from plotly import express as px
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# df.head()
# >   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
# > 0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
# > 1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
# > 2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
# > 3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
# > 4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa

# df.species.unique()
# > array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype=object)

fig = px.scatter(
        df,
        x=df.index,
        y="petal_length",
        #color="species", 
        title='Iris',
    )

updatemenus = [
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label="Plength",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {
                            "y": [df['petal_length']]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Petal length vs index",
                            "yaxis": {"title": "petal_length"},
                        },
                    ],
                ),
                dict(
                    label="Slength",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {
                            "y": [df['sepal_length']]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sepal length vs index",
                            "yaxis": {"title": "sepal_length"},
                        },
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]

# Update layout with the updatemenu
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
```

Weird data, when using the buttons:

```py
from plotly import express as px
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df.index

fig = px.scatter(
        df,
        x=df.index,
        y="petal_length",
        color="species", 
        title='Iris',
    )

updatemenus = [
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label="Plength",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {
                            "y": [df['petal_length']]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Petal length vs index",
                            "yaxis": {"title": "petal_length"},
                        },
                    ],
                ),
                dict(
                    label="Slength",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {
                            "y": [df['sepal_length']]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sepal length vs index",
                            "yaxis": {"title": "sepal_length"},
                        },
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]

# Update layout with the updatemenu
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that internally, using `color="species"` option creates multiple traces in the plot, one for each species type. So we are actually dealing with 3 lines (one for each species), but when I update them using the buttons I tried to set one array only (`"y": [df['petal_length']]`), although we need 3 in this case:  `"y":  [df[df["species"] == pt]["petal_length"] for pt in df["species"].unique()]` (one way to generate the 3 arrays/pd.Series).

```py
from plotly import express as px
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df.index

fig = px.scatter(
        df,
        x=df.index,
        y="petal_length",
        color="species",  # Assuming 'project_type' is a column in the DataFrame
        title='Iris',
    )

updatemenus = [
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label="Plength",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {
                            "y":  [df[df["species"] == pt]["petal_length"]
                                for pt in df["species"].unique()]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Petal length vs index",
                            "yaxis": {"title": "petal_length"},
                        },
                    ],
                ),
                dict(
                    label="Slength",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {
                            "y": [df[df["species"] == pt]["sepal_length"]
                                for pt in df["species"].unique()]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sepal length vs index",
                            "yaxis": {"title": "sepal_length"},
                        },
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]

# Update layout with the updatemenu
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
```